# using getElementById to change background of multiple DIV id's

Tags: javascript, html, getelementbyid

having spent hours on this problem i need to throw it out to the masses. I have a test page at http://sketch360test.co.uk/test.php on which I'm trying to use onclick events to serve two purposes at once... 1) to show/hide various results div (this is working), and 2) to change the background image(s) of the 'question' divs. All of the 'question' divs have a green background image by default (controlled by CSS), a black image on rollover... and I'm trying to get them to each have a black image onclick, as well as resetting the bg image for all the OTHER question divs to green when one is clicked. Hope that makes sense... it should be more obvious if you view the page!

I've managed to get this working for a single instance, ie... clicking either Question 1, Question 2 or Question 3 will turn them to a black bg. This has been done using an inline onclick function to call a css class, for example:

```
<div id="section-menu-1" onclick="this.className='className2';">Question 1</div>
```

I have then added some more javascript to the container for this element (Question 1), which manages to 'reset' or 'revert' the black bg of Question 3 to green. This has been done using the following script:

```
<script type="text/javascript">

function changeClass()
{
 var e = document.getElementById("section-menu-3");
 e.setAttribute('class', 'className1');
 e.setAttribute('className', 'className1'); // for IE which does not recognize "class"
 return;
}
</script>
```

Please note here that I have tried NUMEROUS scripts for changing the class of my DIVs, this is the only one that works consistently. Herein lies the problem though - I want to modify the above script to affect all of the Question ID's, not just "section-menu-3". Incidentally, there are only 3 Questions in this demo but I will have up to 7 or 8 on the final page and so need to modify the above script to be able to take numerous ID's. I've tried things like getElementsByTag but haven't been able to get them to work (perhaps because I'm trying to add a class to an element that I've already applied one to for that process).

Anything else I've tried has ended up breaking the functionality of the above mini-script.

Basically, HELP! [ please :)) ]

Comment: Tried jQuery? That would take care of easily selecting by class (and would work for IE too).

Comment: (quick and dirty demo here http://jsfiddle.net/aSPZd/)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Take a look at this demo: [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/aSPZd/6/)

This should put you in the right direction.

Comment: Hi Paul, thanks so much for this; would it be possible to amend that fiddle slightly to produce the following? I've tried but can't get it moving :(    1) to have Div #1 showing on page load, 2) when you introduce the internal link (ie an <a href> WITHIN Div #3, linking to Div #2) for that internal link to also affect the change on the background image. I'm able to get the internal link to change the div, but it doesn't help with the bg image :(

Comment: @Paul.. i've replicated the fiddle here: <http://www.sketch360test.co.uk/test2.php> and have included the link within Div #3 to Div #2, but am still unable to affect the background image change at the same time.

Comment: have successfully got Div#1 to show on page load just by adding an extra display:block style to that div, whoop whoop :)  but this image swap fired by an internal link business is beyond my range :(   [link](http://www.sketch360test.co.uk/test2.php)

Comment: Try this out: http://jsfiddle.net/aSPZd/6/ (NB: There are many ways to handle this, and I just wrote this out quickly - it may not be the most efficient, but it works with what you have)

Comment: i've discovered a strange issue with the script [link](jsfiddle.net/aSPZd/6) ; when I try to replace an internal link with an external one, e.g. when one of the content divs has a link to an external site, it will not function, even if I remove the .question class from the link - any ideas?

Answer (score 1):

Wrap all your divs in an outer div with an id like so:

```
<div id="section-menu-container">
    <div id="section-menu-1" onclick="this.className='className2';">Question 1</div>
    <div id="section-menu-2" onclick="this.className='className2';">Question 2</div>
    <div id="section-menu-3" onclick="this.className='className2';">Question 3</div>
</div>
```

Then using your javascript function:

```
function changeClass()
{
 var elems = document.getElementById("section-menu-container").getElementByTagName('div');
 elems.setAttribute('class', 'className1');
 elems.setAttribute('className', 'className1'); // for IE which does not recognize "class"
 return;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Basically, you need some kind of generic selector and as Paul above suggests, [jquery](http://jquery.com/) is a great tool. Then you can add a class to your questions, say "myclass". Then, with jquery you do:

$('.myclass').attr("class", "className1");

Alternatively, you can do it with straight up javascript: document.getElementsByClassName('myclass')
will return an array of DOM objects and you need to iterate over each element. However, getElementsByClassName may not be supported in IE versions before IE6 SP1.

Answer (score 0):

How to implement a simple cross browser `getElementsByClassName` function

```
function initializeGetElementsByClassName ()
{
  if (document.getElementsByClassName == undefined) {
    document.getElementsByClassName = function(className)
    {
      var hasClassName = new RegExp("(?:^|\\s)" + className + "(?:$|\\s)");
      var allElements = document.getElementsByTagName("*");
      var results = [];
      var element;
      for (var i = 0; (element = allElements[i]) != null; i++) {
        var elementClass = element.className;
        if (elementClass && elementClass.indexOf(className) != -1 && hasClassName.test(elementClass))
          results.push(element);
        }
        return results;
      }
    }
};

var currentWindowOnLoad = window.onload;

window.onload = function () {
    if (currentWindowOnLoad) {
        currentWindowOnLoad();
    }
    initializeGetElementsByClassName();
};
```

Now using this you can simply do the following:

HTML

```
<div class="sectionMenu" id="id="section-menu-1" ></div>
<div class="sectionMenu" id="id="section-menu-2" ></div>
<div class="sectionMenu" id="id="section-menu-3" ></div>
```

Script

```
var sectionMenus = document.getElementsByClassName("sectionMenu");
for (var i = 0; i < sectionMenus.length; i++) {
  var currentClass = !sectionMenu[i].getAttribute("class") ? sectionMenu[i].getAttribute("classname") : sectionMenu[i].getAttribute("class");
  sectionMenu[i].setAttribute("class", currentclass + " classname1");
  sectionMenu[i].setAttribute("classname", currentclass + " classname1");
}
```

Comment: document.getElementsByTagName("*"); is pretty slow. I don't think it's necessary for him to have a class selector here.

Comment: @PaulPRO ... How do you think jQuery handles this stuff.  For example the following selector $(".classname").  jQuery will first use getElementsByTagName(*) to limit the results and search for a specific class in all DOM Elements. No clearly it would be more efficient to place $("div.classname") and specify the tag but the function above could be modified to handle these efficiencies.

Comment: Yeah... I know. What's your point? He doesn't need jQuery here either.

Comment: @PaulPro My point is I was simply provided a robust and reusable answer to his question.  This function can be reused and tasked for additional purposes.

Comment: Okay, I'll give you that t can be reused. I've made my own version of the same thing just without regex for when I need it, but I don't think a className selector is what he wants here, especially when he is overwriting the class attribute in the function, which means if he set up a certain class for them the function would only work once without extra modifications.

Comment: @PaulPro..  I just explained in my answer how to make that simple modification to make it work more than once.